# vuejs computed value based on component's children

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I'm new to Vuejs, and I'm trying to make an indented tree (following this example: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html), where each node in the tree has two attributes:

- an attribute `value` which is just a number
- an attribute `children` which is a list of nodes (so an empty list if this is a leaf of the tree)

I would like to define a dynamic `computed` property using something like this:

```
sum_values: function() {
    let sum = this.value;
    this.$children.forEach(function (child, index) {
        sum = sum + child.sum_values;
    });
    return sum;
}
```

so that each node has a `sum_values` property which is the sum of all the nodes it contains. But unfortunately, I cannot find a reactive way to do this. My tree is dynamic, and I would like the `sum_values` to update itself after modifications of nodes below in the tree, but modifying `this.value` in a node does not affect the `sum_values` of its parents.

II was trying to find some good ways to do this. I managed to have something working using `this.$emit`, but this is not intuitive and my code is not clean and very error prone. So I was wondering what is the recommended way to do this (whether I should use `Vuex` or a framework like this).

Comment: Why not do it like [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-tree-view?from-embed=&file=/index.html)?  It may make things easier to put the data in Vuex though.

Comment: The example is nice, I like it. But it does not show an example of parent that compute values based on children data.